# Spring Security OAuth2 version 2.0.11 is not bringing me back the token

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I was using version 2.0.10 to request a token and I was receiving the token normally, as below:

```
{
  "access_token": "c15d138a-681e-4e62-98c7-1440fa600686",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": "d7ab807c-f884-4b5d-8013-5f0549d61583",
  "expires_in": 899,
  "scope": "read write" 
}
```

However, after the update to version 2.0.11, when I request using the same url, with the same parameters that I was using to request to the previous version, I only receive

```
{
   "error": "invalid_client",
   "error_description": "Bad client credentials"
}
```

What has changed between this two versions?

This question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283365/spring-boot-oauth2-not-working-properly-on-version-1-4-1)

**EDIT**

I searched what changed between the versions 2.0.10 and 2.0.11 and what I've found was [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/commit/1ed986a8486ab4e84295ee5d0260c790c573e7d7). The class **AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration** overrides now the method **configure**

This is what may be causing the unexpected behavior on version 2.0.11.
And now, the question is, what impacts this is causing that I can't get a token? What should I do to make it work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really a spring oauth security problem. There is an issue open on github.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/896