# POST request "Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

Does anybody encountered the error "Full authentication is required to access this resource" trying to authenticate by using POST request oauth/token?

**Curl command:**

```
curl localhost:85/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d client_id=web_app -d username=reader -d password=reader
```

**Response:**

```
{"timestamp":1486841819620,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","path":"/oauth/token"}
```

**ResourceServerConfiguration configure**

```
http .csrf().disable() .authorizeRequests() .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/me").hasAuthority("FOO_READ")
```

**WebSecurityConfig configure**

```
http .csrf().disable() .exceptionHandling() .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
```

Thanks!

Comment: You, as a *Client*, need to authenticate yourself with the Authorization Server using HTTP Basic authentication

Comment: `Authorization: Basic base64(client_id:client_secret)`

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This error message is from your own back end server. It is a spring framework error. If you check this with 2 providers, you can see that the error message is the same for both. The source of the problem, in my case, was my wrong mapping as a call back url. I configured my server to permit all requests that hit the endpoint `localhost:8080/oauth2/callback/**` to pass without authentication while the callback coming from the providers was configured as `localhost:8080/login/oauth2/**`. I did this mistake following [this](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/) tutorial. For any reason, if there is a mismatch between these configurations, you will get the error.